# Google Analytics 4 with React: No data received in past 48 hours

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I'm trying to get Google Analytics 4 to work with my Create React App but I'm just not having any luck.

I have:

- Created a Google Analytics 4 Property
- Created a web stream
- Tried turning on and off enhanced measurements

To implement analytics in my app I tried with the default script tag:

```
<Helmet>
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-6442DC018S"/>
  <script>
    {`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-6442DC018S');`}
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

This loaded correctly, no errors in my console, I can see the network tab correctly loads the script.

But Google Analytics still shows:
[image]

So I tried using the [`ga-4-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga-4-react) package:

```
  let ga4react;

  if (!GA4React.isInitialized() && MEASUREMENT_ID) {
    ga4react = new GA4React(MEASUREMENT_ID);

    ga4react.initialize().then(
      (ga4) => {
        console.log('success')
        ga4.pageview(window.location.pathname);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Once again, no errors in the console, I see the `success` string (so I assume everything went well.

But unfortunately there's still no data being sent to Analytics.

Any idea what could be happening?

EDIT: I've tried setting up a Google Tag Manager and thanks to the preview mode I can verify data is being set to Google Analytics, however none of it is appearing in GA.

[image]

Comment: I would check with the owner of that project.   GA4 is still beta and that hasnt been update din eight months there have been a lot of changes that may not have been updated in the project.  https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react

Comment: I don't think it's the project, Google Tag Manger tells me it's sending hits to Google Analytics but none of them are actually appearing.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @LeonardoPetrucci?

Comment: @Sheldortheconqueror Yeah, I deleted the analytics property and created a new one. I think Google Analytics is just broken most of the time tbh.